# Continues slider using css3 animation keyframes

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am building a slider using css3. Now slider is running continuously but the flow is not right. After slide 4 the slider is going back from left to right all the way down to the first slide.

What I want after the last slide the first slide should come from right to left as it is coming in manner for other slide.

Will it be possible by css only?

```
@keyframes slide{
  0%{ transform:translateX(0px) }
  25%{ transform:translateX(-200px) }
  50%{ transform:translateX(-400px) }
  75%{ transform:translateX(-600px) }
  100%{ transform:translateX(0px) }
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzxfm7b1/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reason:**

The reason you are seeing this reverse movement is because between 75% and 100% of animation's duration the element image is moving from -600px to 0px. This movement will be gradual just as with the rest of the movement and since there is a significant period of time (1.25s), you get to see it.

---

**Solution 1:** (instant switch between 4 -> 1, may not be what you're after)

You can hide this reverse movement by making sure that the movement from -600px to 0px is done instantaneously. To do this, alter the keyframes like in the below snippet. In this case, the movement from -600px to 0px happens over a very short period of time (0.001% of the animation duration) and so it wouldn't be visible to the eye.

```css
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}
#slideshow img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  animation: slide 5s infinite;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px)
  }
  33.333% {
    transform: translateX(-200px)
  }
  66.666% {
    transform: translateX(-400px)
  }
  99.999% {
    transform: translateX(-600px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/24mia39.jpg">
</div>
```

---

**Solution 2:** (slide movement between 4 -> 1)

Alternately, if you want 4 -> 1 also to be slide movement instead of instantaneous (which may very well be your question) then you may have to use more than one `img` element. The time when 1st image moves out of view (that is goes from -600px to -800px), the second one would start coming in and thus would produce a continuous effect. This wouldn't be possible with a single one.

```css
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}
#slideshow img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  animation: slide 5s infinite;
}
#slideshow img:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 0;
  animation: slide 5s infinite 3.75s;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px)
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-200px)
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-400px)
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-600px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-800px)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/24mia39.jpg">
  <img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/24mia39.jpg">
</div>
```

Below is a variant of the same solution with multiple images instead of one with 4 pieces.

```css
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}
#slideshow img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0;
  animation: slide 5s infinite;
}
#slideshow img:nth-child(2) {
  left: 200px;
  animation: slide 5s infinite;
}
#slideshow img:nth-child(3) {
  left: 200px;
  animation: slide 5s infinite 1.25s;
}
#slideshow img:nth-child(4) {
  left: 200px;
  animation: slide 5s infinite 2.5s;
}
#slideshow img:nth-child(5) {
  left: 200px;
  animation: slide 5s infinite 3.75s;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px)
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-200px)
  }
  50%, 100% {
    transform: translateX(-400px)
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400/4F77AA/FFFFFF">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400/72A94C/FFFFFF">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400/A94F83/FFFFFF">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400/F9E934/FFFFFF">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400/4F77AA/FFFFFF">
</div>
```

---

**Solution 3:** (no need duplicate image if you have separate images)

If you have multiple images instead of one single sprite like image, the cyclic sliding animation can be achieved without duplicating any images also. Below is a variant of vals' answer with a slightly simpler keyframe configuration. (*Note: It is better to preload images to avoid blank screen till they get loaded.*)

```css
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#slideshow img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0;
  animation: slide 5s infinite;
}
#slideshow img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1.25s;
  opacity: 0;
}
#slideshow img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}
#slideshow img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 3.75s;
  opacity: 0;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-200px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50.1%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400/4F77AA/FFFFFF">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400/72A94C/FFFFFF">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400/A94F83/FFFFFF">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400/F9E934/FFFFFF">
</div>
```

Comment: you solution 2 is nice trick. Can we achieve the same in multiple separate image instead having one large image.

Comment: Didn't quite understand you @Carlos. You mean you have 4 or 5 separate images and after the last you want the first one to slide in? If yes, you can use this trick but you'd basically have to duplicate atleast one `img` (the first one). If this is what you need, I'll try making a sample.

Comment: Yes I do have 4 or 5 separate images and after the last I want the first one to slide in

Comment: @Carlos: I just updated the answer, check the 3rd snippet and let me know if its what you need :) As you'd notice, the 5th `img` is the same as the 1st `img` (duplicate).

Comment: A solution is posible without duplicating the image ... See my answer :-)

Comment: @Harry: You last solution is very good. I like it. But it is too complex for me to understand how it is working. Would you please explain what is the logic behind it

Comment: @Carlos: That's pretty simple actually. What happens is that between 0 - 50% the image goes from `translate(200px)` to `translate(-200px)` (that is, from outside view-able area on right to outside view-able area on left - one full slide). Then after that each image goes in the reverse direction back to its original position (which is `translate(200px)`) and during this time the `opacity: 0` makes it invisible. So, by the time it is ready for its next movement, it can come in from the right itself.

Comment: Thanks @Harry ! Can you explain me how can I adapt your last solution to add a pause of 5 seconds on each image? Thank you

Answer (score 6):

I have set a different solution to avoid duplicating the first image

The animation is more complex, but you can reuse it setting delays

```css
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#slideshow img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0;
  animation: slide 5s infinite;
}
#slideshow img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -1.25s;
}
#slideshow img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -2.5s;
}
#slideshow img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -3.75s;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-200px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateX(-200px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  95% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  }
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400/4F77AA/FFFFFF">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400/72A94C/FFFFFF">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400/A94F83/FFFFFF">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400/F9E934/FFFFFF">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes correct. Nice one +1. If it is multiple images then it is possible to play with opacity. If it is single Sprite like image then we can't.

Comment: It can also be achieved with a slightly simpler keyframe configuration like in [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9d0f3xa0/). I've added it to my answer too :)

Comment: Thanks @Vals ! Can you explain me how can I adapt your solution to add a pause of 5 seconds on each image? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The only way I see it possible is if you duplicate the first element on the `img` itself and on the `keyframes` animation on the last step don't go to **0**, instead go to the last element which will be the **1** again. Check this snippet:

```css
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  background: yellow;
}
#slideshow img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  animation: slide 5s infinite;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px)
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-200px)
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-400px)
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-600px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-800px)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ze4efyP.jpg">
</div>
```

---

Final Image for loop will be like this:

[image]

Comment: Yeah that or just a duplicate element with delayed animation like in the second snippet in my answer :) Basically I can't see this being possible without duplication of some sort.

Comment: the images are dynamic. I cant merge it into one

Comment: Yep I think it's better just duplicate the first element than attach again the whole img but you are right I don't see other way @Harry

Comment: Then go with Harry's answer @Carlos

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example of a pure css3 slider which works just as a normal slider and does not have reverse transition. Also much better code and handling. Hope this article helps you and others.

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/#9

This will help in learning and using animation handling on how to make your own slider smooth. Also the guy explained in detail what is needed to build a pure CSS3 slider.

P.S. The people who want to negative mark this are the ones who don't want to learn and understand the technology they are using and are the ones looking for shortcuts.

[**Sample Code**](http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/pEYLYP) as proof that i made using `animation:` after reading and understanding the article above as follows: