# infinite loop slider using keyframes css3

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I was making a slider using css3 keyframes. I don't want my last slide directly jump to first slide. I found some questions related to it and found that duplicating the first image trick will work.

It works fine first time, but second time the first slide take double time compare to normal time which is obvious because last slide and first slide are same.

So is there any way to resolve this issue?

Also I found **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241744/continues-slider-using-css3-animation-keyframes#40241936)**, in this the last solution is too close to answer this question, but the problem is when it starts, its coming from the right i.e `transform:translateX(100%)` which I don't want. I want my image to start from the `transform:translateX(0)`.

So is there any way to make a slider, except repeating the first image, which looks like infinite loop using css3 keyframes having same sliding time

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.images-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-animation: slideToLeft 10s ease infinite;
  animation: slideToLeft 10s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes slideToLeft {
  0%,
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  25%,
  45% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  50%,
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
    transform: translateX(-200%);
  }
  75%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
    transform: translateX(-300%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <div class="images-wrapper">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/ff0000" alt="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/00ff00" alt="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/0000ff" alt="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/ff0000" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idea is to also move the first image to make it at the end to create the duplicate effect. This will be done behind so no one will see it then you can adjust to make the first slide take less time:

```css
.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
}

.images-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  animation: slideToLeft 10s ease infinite 1s;
}
img:first-child {
  z-index:-1;
  animation: image-change 10s ease infinite 1s;
}

@keyframes image-change {
 0%,50% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  70%,100% {
    transform: translateX(300%);
  }
}

@keyframes slideToLeft {
  0%,
  10% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  15%,
  45% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  50%,
  80% {
    transform: translateX(-200%);
  }
  85%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-300%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <div class="images-wrapper">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/ff0000" alt="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/00ff00" alt="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/0000ff" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice approach...but for the first time, first image has less duration as you have used 0 to 10%....any fix for that?

Comment: @Bhuwan you can add a delay at the beginning ;) edited the answer

Comment: how can I show each slide 2 items or 3 items?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a small hack effect, let say your last item is the same as your first you could make a really fast transition the will not be noted by the user... like this..

```css
.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.images-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-animation: slideToLeft 10s ease infinite;
  animation: slideToLeft 10s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes slideToLeft {
  0%,
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  33%,
  63% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  66%,
  96% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
    transform: translateX(-200%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
    transform: translateX(-300%);
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <div class="images-wrapper">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/ff0000" alt="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/00ff00" alt="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/0000ff" alt="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/ff0000" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes its a hack....not sure the sliding interval is same for all slides..

Comment: you can prevent your last transition, directly changing to 100% already correct the answer in that case the sliding interval will be the same, of course it needs to be calibrated..

Comment: I like your idea to play with timings...+1 for this...is there any way without repeating the image trick..?

Answer (score 0):

What was wrong with DaniP's answer?

```css
.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.images-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-animation: slideToLeft 4s ease infinite;
  animation: slideToLeft 4s ease infinite;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes slideToLeft {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  17%,
  33% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  50%,
  66% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
    transform: translateX(-200%);
  }
  83%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
    transform: translateX(-300%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <div class="images-wrapper">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/ff0000" alt="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/00ff00" alt="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/0000ff" alt="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/ff0000" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in your answer the first slide is directly animating to `translateX(-100%)` which is not in my case...

Comment: @Bhuwan Ah you're right, an `animation-delay` fixes this no?