# make div slide continously (linear) using css only

Tags: css

I have a div with 10 childs of 50px each. The div's parent is 210px, how can I make the div slide from right to left continuously, so that after the last div's child appear the first one?

Is this possible using only css? Or only with javascript?

```css
.parent {
  width: 210px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  overflow: hidden
}

.slide {
  display: flex;
  width: 700px;
  animation: slide-left-coins 10s linear 2s infinite
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px
}

@keyframes slide-left-coins {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-600px, 0, 0)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
    <div class="child">7</div>
    <div class="child">8</div>
    <div class="child">9</div>
    <div class="child">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need JavaScript

Comment: A solution using CSS only is covered [in this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/) :o)

Comment: Yeah I was thinking on something similar, making php print the first childs after the last one and play with the translate3d(), but maybe it's better to just use javascript...

Comment: you may get some idea here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948392/infinite-loop-slider-using-keyframes-css3/48949285#48949285

Comment: That CSS Tricks solution wouldn't work here because it uses the `background-repeat` property of backgrounds to show the wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

While this is possible by repeating html, it may be better to just use javascript.

But for those css-only hardcores, here's my approach:

```css
.parent {
  width: 210px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  overflow: hidden
}

.slide {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: auto;
  animation: slide-left-coins 10s linear 2s infinite
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px
}

@keyframes slide-left-coins {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-350px)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For this to work, we need to know the slide's width (that in most cases we know, and we can almost always make it static by giving it a fixed width or if we know it's not gonna change, then get it). I got this by multiplying the total number of childs by their width (including the margin and anything else that adds width to the parent):

`child's width: 50px + child's margin: 20px (10 to each side) = 70px`

So each child takes exactly 70px of width, now multiply this by the total number of childs:

`70px * 10 = 700px`

This is the slide's width, now we divide:

`700px / 2 = 350px`

This is the distance the slide has to travel. From right to left it needs to be negative, so finally we've got:

`translateX(-350px)`

If you're not using a fixed width but you know the content is not gonna change then go to the inspector and in the layout tab you can get the slide's width (just remember that the width can be different across browsers, I did use hack selectors to workaround that).

To explain a little why this works: `translateX()` needs half this width, that way it will go to the middle of the slide, that's where the content (the 5 childs) have completely disappeared and only the repeated content is visible, then it starts again without the eye noticing anything.

This is just for demonstration purposes, if you really want to do this you don't need to repeat everything, just what's visible at the start (that's what's really needed).