# First img of bannermover does not follow directly after last img of bannermove

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I use the following code to create a bannermove:

```css
.photobanner {
  height: 233px;
  width: 3550px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.photobanner img {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  height: 233px;
  width: 350px;
}

.photobanner img {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.first {
  animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes bannermove {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -2130px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="photobanner">
  <img class="first" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/450x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/550x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/650x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/750x150">
</div>
```

You can also find the code in the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dw47z3jy/2/). 
All this works fine so far.

---

However, right now when the animation reaches the last `img 750x150` it continues the animation until this image left the screen. However, I want that after the `img 750x150` the first `img 350x150` appears without any break or empty space in the animation.

What do I have to change in my code to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948392/infinite-loop-slider-using-keyframes-css3/48949285#48949285 (without duplication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you means to [this](https://designshack.net/articles/css/infinitephotobanner/) tutorial. The key sentence is:

> What we need to do is make our first frame perfectly match our last frame

and for doing this you have to add more images so they will take the blank space.

```css
.photobanner {
  height: 233px;
  width: 3550px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.photobanner img {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  height: 233px;
  width: 350px;
}

.photobanner img {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.first {
  animation: bannermove 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes bannermove {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1775px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="photobanner">
  <img class="first" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/450x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/550x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/650x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/750x150">
  
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/450x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/550x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/650x150">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to go with yor solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/dw47z3jy/29/ It seems to work but when the animation reaches 700x100 in the jsfiddle it changes the images and "jumps" back to the first. Is there a way to make this more smoother without this "jump"?

Comment: You have to remember the key sentence: `What we need to do is make our first frame perfectly match our last frame`. So duplicate `.photobanner`, set its `margin-left` as the final value you defined in the `bannermove` animation and make sure it looks the same (except the edge of the image from the left). Tell me how it goes.

Comment: I tried your solution but I still could not make it work :-( Do you see where is my mistake: https://jsfiddle.net/dw47z3jy/37/

Comment: You didn't add slides as I (and the tutorial did). I just fixed your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rkxocgt5/1/ but try to understand the principle.

Comment: Ahhhh. o.k. now since I compare your jsfiddle with mine I see the point. Thanks a lot for the addtional explanation and for helping me to learn how the principle works.

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck!