# Infinite background colour cycle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this background image changer that works really well. However, I need this to be an infinite loop, so after the red, it goes back to the orange and starts the cycle again. Can anyone help with this?

Feel free to use wither css html or javascript.

Please help!

```css
:root {
  --animate-duration: 2000ms;
}

#home .bgslider {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ffc60b;
}

#home .box {
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#home .ediv2 {
  background: #90a0d6;
  z-index: 10;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

#home .ediv3 {
  background: #ff6666;
  z-index: 20;
  animation-delay: 10s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

  <meta content="" name="descriptison">
  <meta content="" name="keywords">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css">


</head>

<body>

  <section id="home">
    <div class="bgslider">
      <div class="box ediv2 animate__animated animate__slideInRight"></div>
      <div class="box ediv3 animate__animated animate__slideInRight"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can use CSS `@keyframes` for this. That'll be lot easier. [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp)

Comment: I cant because the colour should go from orange, to blue to red. It shouldn't fade in between like it does with `@keyframes`. Please have a look at the minimalistic reproducible example for an example of what i mean. @DebsmitaPaul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll explain what I did here.

1. I used `@keyframes` as I mentioned in the comment. So i removed the `ediv1` and `ediv2` divisions as they are not required.
2. I have defined a keyframe rule called `magicColor` and applied it to the `.bgslider` class.

```css
:root {
  --animate-duration: 2000ms;
}

#home .bgslider {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*background-color: #ffc60b;*/
  animation: magicColor 3s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:steps(1, end); /* use this to prevent fade effect */
}

@keyframes magicColor {
0% { background-color: #ffc60b; }
50% { background: #90a0d6; }
100% { background: #ff6666; }
}

#home .box {
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/*
#home .ediv2 {
  background: #90a0d6;
  z-index: 10;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

#home .ediv3 {
  background: #ff6666;
  z-index: 20;
  animation-delay: 10s;
}*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

  <meta content="" name="descriptison">
  <meta content="" name="keywords">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css">


</head>

<body>

  <section id="home">
    <div class="bgslider">
      <!--<div class="box ediv2 animate__animated animate__slideInRight"></div>
      <div class="box ediv3 animate__animated animate__slideInRight"></div>-->
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

**Edit:** So I was unable to see the sliding effect in your code snippet. Here is the proper and **pure CSS** solution to the question.

```css
.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.images-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.images-wrapper .slide {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.images-wrapper .slide.one {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
}

.images-wrapper .slide.two {
  background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

.images-wrapper .slide.three {
  background-color: rgb(0,255,0);
}

.images-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  animation: slideToLeft 10s ease infinite;

  animation: slideToLeft 5s ease infinite 1s;
}

.slide.one {
  z-index: -1;
  animation: image-change 5s ease infinite 1s;
}

@keyframes image-change {
  0%,
  50% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  70%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(300%);
  }
}

@keyframes slideToLeft {
  0%,
  10% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  15%,
  45% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  50%,
  80% {
    transform: translateX(-200%);
  }
  85%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-300%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <div class="images-wrapper">
    <!--
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/ff0000" alt="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20**strong text**0x200/00ff00" alt="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/0000ff" alt="">
    -->

    <div class="slide one"></div>
    <div class="slide two"></div>
    <div class="slide three"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2:** This is to make the sections full screen.

```css
.inner {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.images-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.images-wrapper .slide {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
}

.images-wrapper .slide.one {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
}

.images-wrapper .slide.two {
  background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

.images-wrapper .slide.three {
  background-color: rgb(0,255,0);
}

.images-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  animation: slideToLeft 10s ease infinite;

  animation: slideToLeft 5s ease infinite 1s;
}

.slide.one {
  z-index: -1;
  animation: image-change 5s ease infinite 1s;
}

@keyframes image-change {
  0%,
  50% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  70%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(300%);
  }
}

@keyframes slideToLeft {
  0%,
  10% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  15%,
  45% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  50%,
  80% {
    transform: translateX(-200%);
  }
  85%,
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-300%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <div class="images-wrapper">
    <!--
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/ff0000" alt="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/00ff00" alt="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200/0000ff" alt="">
    -->

    <div class="slide one"></div>
    <div class="slide two"></div>
    <div class="slide three"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:**

I have taken reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948392/infinite-loop-slider-using-keyframes-css3).

Comment: This is correct however the sliding animation is now gone. Is there a way to bring it back but keep the infinite loop? @DebsmitePaul

Comment: Oh okay... What kind of sliding animation?

Comment: Look at the minimalistic reproducible example I provided. It has the sliding effect applied when the colour changes. I am using `animate.css` for this

Comment: If you're unable to implement the sliding effect the same way I did, you can use javascript to recreate it... I'm just unsure of how to do that

Comment: Wait, I can't see any sliding effect in the code snippet you provided. If you can see it that means my browser is trash. It has happened before smh. I'll use another one. I will update answer once I figure it out.

Comment: Sure thing. Try using Google Chrome to see it. It works on my screen using chrome. Also works on Safari if you dont want to use chrome

Comment: I use brave browser, and I don't know what is happening with it, many animations are not showing like when you open a new tab that slow and smooth animation is gone. Okay I saw it on Microsoft Edge and saw the sliding effect. I'll try to implement it.

Comment: Feel free to use javascript to implement this. CSS animation can be annoying to deal with especially if you want to use the infinite loop you have added.

Comment: Yeah I thought of using jQuery but then searched if there is any pure CSS way of doing it. Found this brilliant **pure CSS** slider [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948392/infinite-loop-slider-using-keyframes-css3). Give it a try. The accepted answer is the one.

Comment: This is great. Is there a way of doing it with just background colours? If so, please update your answer with something that will solve the issue. Thank you

Comment: Ok I'll update.

Comment: @asohasf1241 Hi sorry for the late reply, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Amazing!!! Thank you very much

Comment: Sorry about this. I wanted it to be full screen: `width: 100% height 100%` but when I try do this, 3 boxes appear.

Comment: okay i'll update the answer. No worries.

Comment: There you go :)

Comment: Great work! Again, thank you

Comment: Hope this helps. And a side note - if you want to increase/decrease the speed, just play around with the `animation` property in the two places.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223137/discussion-between-asohasf1241-and-debsmita-paul).

Comment: Hi! As we discussed in chat, here is the jQuery solution using jQuery plugin Slick. There you [go](https://codepen.io/debsmita/pen/bGepgZo)

Answer (score 1):

We use [CSS gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) for the colors. As for the animations, there are two ways to achieve this:

### CSS Transforms

As [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64384139/infinite-background-colour-cycle/64384296#comment113850035_64384296), it is possible to achieve this with [CSS transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform):

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bgslider {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ffc60b 25%, #ff6666 25% 50%, #90a0d6 50% 75%, #ffc60b 75% 100%);
  animation: slide 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
  33% {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
  66% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-75%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bgslider"></div>
```

### CSS Positioning

You can also make do with CSS [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). However, this method is not recommended due to [staggering performance](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/).

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bgslider {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ffc60b 25%, #ff6666 25% 50%, #90a0d6 50% 75%, #ffc60b 75% 100%);
  animation: slide 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
  33% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  66% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -300%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bgslider"></div>
```

### Bonus: Controlling color duration

You can control the color duration on screen with some small modifications to the code:

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  --color-duration: 5s;
}

.bgslider {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ffc60b 25%, #ff6666 25% 50%, #90a0d6 50% 75%, #ffc60b 75% 100%);
  animation: slide calc(var(--color-duration) * 4) infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  25%, 33% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50%, 66% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75%, 100% {
    left: -300%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bgslider"></div>
```

Comment: Please look at the other answers that have suggested this. This is incorrect.

Comment: I changed the answer.. Please look above ^

Comment: @barhatsor **Don't** animate by position properties like `left` `top` etc. We have the GPU accelerated `transform` for that purpose.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan What would be the solution to this without using position properties? How do you use the `transform` property to solve this issue?

Comment: Also @barhatsor is there a way to make it wait on the colour for 5 seconds, and then transition to the next colour?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I added to the answer. Check above ^

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You're right. Made it first, with a disclaimer on using CSS positioning.

Comment: @asohasf1241 see the end of the answer :)

Comment: The transition needs to be 3 seconds. Each colour should show for 10 seconds (including the first colour when you refresh the page). Is this possible? @barhatsor

Answer (score 0):

You can set the animation-iteration-count to infinite on the css. If the first color is the same as the last it will seem infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

Try out :https://codepen.io/metagrapher/pen/tgcLl

```
<section id="message">
<h1>Rainbow<br/>Goodness</h1>
<p>So this is currently set to color cycle every 175 seconds, which is the same as 60 seconds per color divided by two, or 30 seconds per color, assuming roygbiv, even though I only programmed Red, Green, and Blue. The timing itself should actually make it so that each color gets its time, as no color should be a rest, anyhow. Arguably I should have done more to get the full rainbow. We hardly touched the luminosity spectrum, although I think some of that does make it in.</p>
<p>The font color looping is based on a Cyan-Magenta-Yellow loop, as the opposite of RGB.</p></section>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
      animation: colorchange 2s linear 1s infinite; /* animation-name followed by duration in seconds*/
         /* you could also use milliseconds (ms) or something like 2.5s */
      -webkit-animation: colorchange 2s linear 0s infinite alternate; /* Chrome and Safari */
    }

    @keyframes colorchange
    {
      0%   {background: red; color: cyan;}
      33%  {background: green; color: magenta;}
      66%  {background: blue; color: yellow;}
      100% {background: red; color: cyan;}
   }

    @-webkit-keyframes colorchange /* Safari and Chrome - necessary duplicate */
    {
      0%   {background: red; color: cyan;}
      33%  {background: green; color: magenta;}
      66%  {background: blue; color: yellow;}
      100% {background: red; color: cyan;}
   }
section {
  width: 33vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#message {
  text-align: center;
  color: inherit;
  opacity: 75%;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  font-family: Cooper Black, Helvetica, Arial;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 4.69em;
}
p {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial;
}
```

Comment: No, the colours should not fade in and out. Please look at the minimalistic reproducible example for reference.